# Can I extract an associative array into variables?

Tags: twig

Lets say I have an associative array like so:

```
{% set settings = { 'foo':'bar', 'cat':'mouse', 'apple':'banana' } %}
```

To use this data I would do the following:

```
{{ settings.foo }}
{{ settings.cat }}
{{ settings.apple }}
```

However, I wondered if there is a way to extract the keys to variables, and the values to values? Essentially the same as the [PHP Extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. So I can just do this instead:

```
{{ foo }}
{{ cat }}
{{ apple }}
```

My very amateurish attempt to do this started out like this:

```
{% for key,val in settings %}
  {% set key = val %}
{% endfor %}
```

But obviously that doesn't work (or I wouldn't be here). Is there another approach I could take?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As most things in Twig this can be done by extending `Twig`

<kbd>ProjectTwigExtension.php</kbd>

```
class ProjectTwigExtension extends Twig_Extension {

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('extract', array($this, 'extract'), ['needs_context' => true, ]),
        );
    }

    public function extract(&$context, $value) {
        foreach($value as $k => $v) $context[$k] = $v;
    }       

    public function getName() {
        return 'ProjectTwigExtension';
    }        
}
```

<kbd>Register class in Twig</kbd>

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new ProjectTwigExtension());
```

<kbd>template.twig</kbd>

```
{{ extract({'foo': 'bar', }) }}
{{ foo }} {# output : bar #}
```

---

*(sidenote)* Seems you can't do this by using a closure (see example below) because the compiler of `Twig` passes the variables in an array, thus creating a copy

<kbd>With closure</kbd>

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('extract',   function (&$context, $value) {
    foreach($value as $k => $v) $context[$k] = $v;
}, ['needs_context' => true, ]));
```

<kbd>Compiled result</kbd>

```
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, call_user_func_array($this->env->getFunction('extract')->getCallable(), array($context, array("foo" => "bar", "foobar" => "foo"))), "html", null, true);
```

Comment: Thank you the in-depth solution DarkBee. I never expected is to be as convoluted as this, but it does work. I'm working with Craft CMS, so the sidenote you mentioned didn't apply to me in the end. Thanks again, very happy with this!

Comment: Good catch! It will replace existing variable? As example foo already defined in the context? Or give an error? Only for curiosity...

Comment: Current code would overwrite any existing variable in the context